# Alert when uploading file with php

Tags: php, file, upload

I have a file upload page that works but I'm trying to do some error alerts to choose if you want to replace or not.
This is my php file that does the upload

```
<?php
require ("connect.php");
$filename = "docs/".$_FILES['datafile']['name']."";
$d=explode(".",$_FILES['datafile']['name']);
if (file_exists($filename)) {
 echo "<script>alert('Full dump for ".$d[0]." already exists.')</script>";
 $error = 1;
} else {
   $target_path = "docs/";
   $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['datafile']['name']); 
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['datafile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
   {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['datafile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
    $error = 0;
   }
   else
    {
     echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
     $error = 1;
    }
}
if ($error != 1)
{
 $r1 = mysql_query("insert into full_dump (file_name) values ('".$_FILES['datafile']['name']."')")or die(mysql_error());
 $file1 = "docs/".$_FILES['datafile']['name']."";
 $lines = file($file1); 
 $count = count($lines);
 $fp = fopen("docs/".$_FILES['datafile']['name']."","r");
 $data=fread($fp,filesize("docs/".$_FILES['datafile']['name'].""));
 $tmp=explode ("\n", $data);
 for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
 {
  $a=$tmp[$i];
  $b=$i+1;
  $r2 = mysql_query("update full_dump set field_".$b."='".$a."' where file_name='".$_FILES['datafile']['name']."'")or die(mysql_error());
 }
echo"</br>";
echo "Uploading Complete</br>";
echo "Uploaded File Info:</br>";
echo "Sent file: ".$_FILES['datafile']['name']."</br>";
echo "File size: ".$_FILES['datafile']['size']." bytes</br>";
echo "File type: ".$_FILES['datafile']['type']."</br>";
}
?>
```

What I want to have is instead of

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
 echo "<script>alert('Full dump for ".$d[0]." already exists.')</script>";
 $error = 1;
}
```

to have an alert if I would like to replace the file or not. If it's yes it would replace the file, delete the old record in the db and insert the new record. I it's no don't do nothing...or show a message "canceled by user". Could I have $error to be assigned a value for YES or NO on user choosing or not to replace?

UPDATE
This is the form page for upload.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="Javascript">
function fileUpload(form, action_url, div_id) {
// Create the iframe...    
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");    
iframe.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe");    
iframe.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe");    
iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");    
iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");    
iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");    
iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");     
// Add to document...    
form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);    
window.frames['upload_iframe'].name = "upload_iframe";     
iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");     
// Add event...    
var eventHandler = function () {             
    if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload", eventHandler);            
        else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);             
    // Message from server...            
    if (iframeId.contentDocument) {                
    content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;            
    } 
        else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {                
            content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;            
        } 
            else if (iframeId.document) {                
                content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;            
            }             
    document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = content;             
    // Del the iframe...            
    setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)', 250);        
}     
if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);    
if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler);     
// Set properties of form...    
form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");    
form.setAttribute("action", action_url);    
form.setAttribute("method", "post");    
form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");    
form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");     
// Submit the form...    
form.submit();     
document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = "Uploading...";}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<form enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"POST\">
    <input type="file" name="datafile" />
    <input type="button" value="upload" onClick="fileUpload(this.form,'file_upload.php','upload'); return false;" >
    <div id="upload"></div>
</form>
<?php
require("connect.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM full_dump")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "Job number: <a href=\"pdf.php?job=".$row['file_name']."\"target=\"_blank\">".$row['file_name']."</a></br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should do this with ajax... 
when you will send **ajax** request you will check if file **exist** or **not** .. if yes return eg -1 and ask user for **relapsing**  ...

---

**Enjoy :)**

Comment: I've updated the question. Could you give me hint on where to add the ajax code? I know how to check if file exists with php but got no idea on ajax.

Comment: would you be able to be more specific, as is some code please? i'm very new to ajax

Comment: inside function fileUpload(); use jquery ajax functionality here is exlample http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp

Answer (score 0):

instead of using upload code on same page. do one thing, upload file by using ajax request. then check on backend site file is aleady exist or not and according to that show message as you like